# Mutt and character sets issue

Tags: mutt, unicode, character-encoding

I updated to mutt 1.10.0 and now my character sets are all messed up. They worked fine with 1.5.21 -- system version and now old. Following [the FAQ](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/wikis/MuttFaq/Charset), I have these set up:

```
; echo $TERM                                                                    
screen-256color-bce                                                                                               
; locale                                                                        
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8                                                                
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8                                                            
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                          
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                        
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                           
LC_COLLATE=C                                                                    
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                       
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                       
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                          
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                           
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                        
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                      
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                    
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"                                                 
LC_ALL=
```

UTF-8 character such as `Consulat général de France` appear fine in less (my pager but also in neovi) but appear as `Consulat gM-CM-)nM-CM-)ral de France` in the menu.

I do have `set config_charset=utf-8` set in my `~/.muttrc`.

Comment: If you compile/link with **ncurses** rather than ***ncursesw*** it will behave that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile/link with **ncurses** rather than ***ncursesw*** it will behave that way.

The *`"M-"`* prefix is used for character codes 160-255 when the locale settings tell ncurses that the code is nonprinting.  UTF-8 contains a lot of those codes.